# LinkedList clear method

Tags: java, linked-list

Suppose I have this portion of the code. And I have output. 
allValues: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], []].
When I make *listOfValues2* clear(). I want that only that list was cleared without affecting values in the *allValues* list. How can I make it? 
I need this because later I will generate another *listOfValues2* with another data set and will put into *allValues* as third list.

```
     LinkedList<Integer> listOfValues1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
     LinkedList<Integer> listOfValues2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
     LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> allValues= 
     new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

     for(int w=0; w<=10; w++) {
        listOfValues1.add(w);
     }

     for(int b=5; b<=15; b++) {
        listOfValues2.add(b);
     }

     allValues.add(listOfValues1);
     allValues.add(listOfValues2);
     listOfValues2.clear();
     System.out.println("allValues: " + allValues);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need this because later I will generate another listOfValues2 with another data set and will put into AllValues as third list.

Then don't clear `listOfValues2`. Create new `LinkedList` later and assign it to the `listOfValues2` variable. Any changes you do with the original `listOfValues2` will take place in the `allValues` too, because `listOfValues2` and the second element of `allValues` share the same reference to the list of objects.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you need to do this.

```
AllValues.add(new LinkedList<Integer>(listOfValues2)); // this will create a new list with all the values of listOfValues2
```

Because, if you just add the `listOfValues2`, any changes made to it will be reflected in the `AllValues` as well.

Answer (score 2):

The collection classes are not immutable and hence do not support sharing. Therefore, you can't do it the way you tried. If you need an empty list, just say:

```
listOfValues2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of listOfValues2. Add that to AllValues instead of listOfValues2.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use the `clone()` method of your `LinkedList` so that you will only add a clone of `listOfValues2` into `AllValues`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> listOfValues1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> listOfValues2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> AllValues = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

        for (int w = 0; w <= 10; w++) {
            listOfValues1.add(w);  
        }

        for (int b = 5; b <= 15; b++) {
            listOfValues2.add(b);  
        }

        AllValues.add(listOfValues1);

        // adding a cloned Linkedlist        
        AllValues.add((LinkedList<Integer> ) listOfValues2.clone());
        System.out.println("AllValues: " + AllValues);
        listOfValues2.clear();
        System.out.println("AllValues: " + AllValues);  
    }
}
```

The point here is when you create a clone of your list, `AllValues` will no longer referring to the `listOfValues2`. So any update to `listOfValues2` list will not be visible to the `AllValues`.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should either put a **copy** of listOfValues2 to AllValues or generate another data into third separate list.

Answer (score 0):

i think linkedlist always refer memory instead of value.
so you clear the list2 then that particular memory has no value.
Again allValue list refer same memory location, there no value existing. so it print empty for list2.